# What is this old tile game I inherited?

Tags: identify-this-game

I have an old tile game with rectangular tiles, ivory, with different colored numbers on them. Some have 2 numbers one on top and one on bottom, others have one number with words on top like draw two, skip, reverse, dead end. It has racks to put the tiles on. It reminds me of Rummikub or Uno, but each tile has either 2 numbers or a number and words. I need directions for play and the name of the game.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like [Uno Dominos](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/3839/uno-dominos).

Looking at the Board Game Geek -site for the game (linked above), I found [these instructions](http://www.centralconnector.com/GAMES/unodominos.html) on how to play.

[image: Picture of Uno Dominos box, racks and tiles in bags.]
The design shown in the picture above seems to be a pretty common one. There's another kind of tile design, done by Mattel, that can be seen in some images on the Board Game Geek -site and the instructions linked above. The rules should be the same regardless of what the tiles look like.